# "uninitialized constant Google::Apis" when calling google API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, ruby-on-rails-5

Using https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ruby api for google calendar and event listing.

When running that code getting this error at SCOPE = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR_READONLY

I have google-api-client (= 0.8.2) gem

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: uninitialized constant Google::Apis

Comment: try this gem 'google-api-client', '0.8.2', require: 'google/api_client'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're using 0.8.2 gem. According to this [google github post](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/d2e51b4e7d4cb5a18cb08b2aed9c0d8ffff14b22/MIGRATING.md#discovery), you ought to use

```
  Google::APIClient.new
```

instead of

```
  Google::Apis
```

Comment: Yes, it's api version problem. I refer http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/file/MIGRATING.md#API_Methods doc. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Glad I can help :)